# How to track conversions without a confirmation page

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, web-analytics, event-tracking

I have a form on my site that, upon a successful completion, triggers a confirmation message in a modal.  I need to be able to track the conversions on this form.  I think I need an event tracker here, but I can't figure out where I'd put it.

The form is at http://www.nearlynewlywed.com/a/sell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to create a virtual page view that will simulate a "thank you" page that will trigger the goal.

Execute this JS code when the form is validated and submitted:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/your-directory/form/thank-you']);
```

If you use Universal Analytics, then:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/your-directory/form/thank-you');
```

Now the thank you page will be rendered as a pageview, which will appears on your reports and Goals' funnel visualization. Remember to set the "/your-directory/form/thank-you" as the goal destination on Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should push and event to GA when your form is validated and it passes. That means, if every field is ok, then at the same time you send the command to open the modal window you send a ga tracking command like this.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Success', 'Form x was completed']);
```

You could do something like this with jQuery

```
$('#formId').on('submit', function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Success', 'Form x was completed']);
});
```

OR add this to your form HTML tag

```
<form action="action.php" onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Success', 'Form x was completed'])">
```